# Get missed records using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the records from two tables. My example table structure is below. My table and expected output is given below. Am new for this field. Please help me to create this..
Code may be in SQL or Mysql

```
Table 1   

Id   name
101  xx
102  xxx
103  ccc
104  cc
105  vv


Table 2     
Id   name category
101  xx   ww
102  xxx  qq
```

I want to get the output like this

```
Id   name  category
101  xx    ww
102  xxx   qq
103  ccc
104  cc
105  vv
```

Comment: you need left join if you want all results from left table. why do you  have both id and name that looks same in first and second table? is those values the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  t1.name,
  t2.category
FROM
  t1 LEFT JOIN t2
  ON t1.id=t2.id AND t1.name=t2.name
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db53b/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT Table_1.Id, Table_1.name, category 
FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.Id=Table_2.Id
```

Also, why do you have redundancy in your tables?